# createing a centered scaled bitmap

Tags: android

So I have some code that takes a video and grabs a frame using MediaMetadataRetriever's getFrameAtTime. This works great so far. However I want to list the videos recorded in a listview and have an accompanying thumbnail used by the getFrameAtTime screen grabs. The screen grabs do not save as squares and using createBitmap with even width/height dimensions could have contorted thumbnails. Any idea how I can fix this? Or maybe non-square rectangular thumbnails would work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Set the bitmap as a background of `ImageView` - `imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);` and set the scale type to `FIT_CENTER` - `imageView.setScaleType(FIT_CENTER);`